# How to capitalize all sheet except specific columns on Google spreadsheet using Google Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This code capitalize all the sheet cells, except some columns as required. Nevertheless, formulas into the excluded cells are deleted.
I do not want the script erase my formulas into these columns.

```js
function onOpen() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.createMenu('Eta Buddy')
        .addItem('Capitalize', 'proper')
        .addToUi();
}


function proper() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
excludedCols = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
s.getDataRange()
    .setValues(
        s.getDataRange()
        .getValues()
        .map(function (r) {
            return r.map(function (el, i) {
               return !el ? null : (typeof el !== 'string' && el) || excludedCols.indexOf(i + 1) > -1 ? el : toTitleCase(el);
            })
        })
    )
}

function toTitleCase(str) {
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt) {
        return txt.charAt(0)
            .toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1)
            .toLowerCase();
    });
}
```

Comment: first show us your attempts at doing such change and what isnt working. otherwise question is not on topic for s.o.

Answer (score 0):

Please take note of Zig's comment. Since very little needs to be changed, replace your proper function with the one below and see if that works..

UPDATED CODE (to save the formulas in the excluded columns, see comment)

```
function proper() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
    excludedCols = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
formulas = s.getDataRange()
    .getFormulas()
s.getDataRange()
    .setValues(
        s.getDataRange()
        .getValues()
        .map(function (r, j) {
            return r.map(function (el, i) {
                return !el ? null : formulas[j][i] ? formulas[j][i] :
                    (typeof el !== 'string' && el) || excludedCols.indexOf(i + 1) > -1 ? el : toTitleCase(el);
            })
        })
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is not working. It is deleting my formulas into column 2, 4, 6, 8, 10.

Comment: In your first post (before the edit) you didn't mention the formulas. I updated the code so that formulas will remain untouched in the whole sheet. See if that works for you ?